# how to skip line when parsing text file?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

This is the text file

```
gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassVisitor 13 2 0 14 74 34 2 9

gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer 3 1 0 3 18 0 2 2

gr.spinellis.ckjm.MetricsFilter 7 1 0 6 30 11 2 5

gr.spinellis.ckjm.PrintPlainResults 2 1 0 2 8 0 1 2

gr.spinellis.ckjm.MethodVisitor 11 2 0 21 40 0 1 8

gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler 1 1 0 1 1 0 3 1
```

and this is the code I have written to pars through, I want to skip to one line in between the values, by the way I already skipped the first line by reading one line before entering the while loop .

```
package javaapplication39;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*  to read CSV file in Java. In this program we will read * list of metrics  stored in CSV file as comma separated values. */
public class readallvalues {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\1.txt");

        // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
        for (Metrics m : metric) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }

    private static List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {
        List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
        // create an instance of BufferedReader
        // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
            br.readLine();
            String line1=null;
            // read the first line from the text file
            String line = br.readLine();                 
            while (line != null) { // loop until all lines are read                      
                String[] attributes = line.split(" ");  // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
                metricsss.add(valueOfMetric);      // adding metric  into ArrayList
                //skip empty line 
                // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n"))

                line = br.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return metricsss;
    }

    private static Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
        String name = metadata[0];
        int WMC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
        int DIT = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
        int NOC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
        int CBO = Integer.parseInt(metadata[4]);
        int RFC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[5]);
        int LCOM= Integer.parseInt(metadata[6]);
        int Ce  = Integer.parseInt(metadata[7]);
        int NPM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[8]);
        return new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC,CBO,RFC,LCOM,Ce,NPM);//,cc
    }
}

class Metrics {
    private String name;
    private int WMC;
    private int DIT;
    private int NOC;
    private int CBO;
    private int RFC;
    private int LCOM;   
    private int Ce;
    private int NPM;

    public Metrics( String name,int WMC,int DIT,int NOC,int CBO,int RFC,int LCOM, int Ce, int NPM) {
        this.name = name;
        this. WMC  =WMC ;
        this. DIT  =DIT ;
        this. NOC = NOC;
        this. CBO =CBO ;
        this. RFC = RFC;
        this.LCOM = LCOM;
        this.Ce =Ce ;
        this. NPM = NPM;           
    }

    public String getName() {        return name;    }
    public void setName(String name) {        this.name = name;    }

    public int getWMC()          {         return WMC     ;     }
    public void setWMC(int WMC)  {        this.WMC = WMC  ;     }

        //WMC, DIT, NOC, CBO, RFC,LCOM, Ca, Ce, NPM,LCOM3,LOC, DAM, MOA, MFA, CAM,IC, CBM and AMC ,cc
    public int getDIT()          {         return DIT     ;     }
    public void setDIT(int DIT)  {        this.DIT = DIT  ;     }


    public int getNOCC()          {         return NOC     ;     }
    public void setNOC(int NOC)  {        this.NOC = NOC  ;     }


    public int getCBO()          {         return CBO     ;     }
    public void setCBO(int CBO)  {        this.CBO = CBO  ;     }

    public int getRFC()          {         return RFC     ;     }
    public void setRFC(int RFC)  {        this.RFC = RFC  ;     }

    public int getLCOM()          {         return LCOM     ;     }
    public void setLCOM(int LCOM)  {        this.LCOM = LCOM  ;     }

      public int getCe()          {         return Ce     ;     }
    public void setCe(int Ce)  {        this.Ce = Ce  ;     }

    public int getNPM()          {         return NPM     ;     }
    public void setNPM(int NPM)  {        this.NPM = NPM  ;     }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "name=  " + name +" WMC= " + WMC + " DIT= " + DIT + " NOC " + NOC   + " CBO " + CBO 
                    + " RFC " + RFC + " LCOM " + LCOM + " Ce " + Ce + " NPM " + NPM   +"\n\n" ;//+ " cc " + cc 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading `br.readLine();` outside the loop, just below the try with resource declaration, which *skips* the very first line.

Add `br.readLine()` call at the end of `while` loop, to skip empty line. Problem with this is it will also skip line with text if your file has two consecutive empty lines instead of one.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   //..logic
   br.readLine();//add call to skip this line
}
```

You should better check whether line is empty or not to perform your logic.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   //trim will remove leading and trailing white space characters
  if(!"".equals(line.trim())  {
     //..logic
  }
}
```

Apart from that you should follow naming convention, class name should start with capital case. So, your class name should be `ReadAllvalues`.